# Using calculations within Classes

Tags: c++, class

[image]The program is working, but with one exception it can not seem to calculate profit. Here is my code, I believe I made a stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't seem to locate the fault.

```
    double getProfit() const;       
    void setRprice(double);     
    void setWprice(double);     
    void setProfit(double);
};

    string Item::getName() const{    return name;  }
        void Item::setName(string n){name = n;}

double Item::getRprice() const{ return rprice; }
    void Item::setRprice(double r){rprice = r;}

double Item::getWprice() const{ return wprice; }
    void Item::setWprice(double w){wprice = w;}

double Item::getProfit() const{ return profit; }
    void Item::setProfit(double p){profit = p;}

void setValues(Item&); void getValues(const Item&);

void setValues(Item& g){
   string n; 
   double r,w,p; 
   p=r-w;

   cout << "Enter brand name of item: "; 
   cin >> n;
   cout << "Enter retail price: "; 
   cin >> r;
   cout << "Enter wholesale price: "; 
   cin >> w;
   g.setName  (n); 
   g.setRprice(r); 
   g.setWprice(w); 
   g.setProfit(p); 
}
```

It will output brand name, retail, and wholesale prices so I know for a fact it's storing the outputs I want. I am curious as to why it won't take my stored values and use them to calculate the profit as I instructed it to. Does it have anything to do with my profit being a const?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Also I don't see any calculations done in your code, so why do expect any would be applied?

Comment: the calculation defines a new variable p and sets it equal to r (retail price) and subtracts w (wholesale price).

Comment: I have no clue about which _calculation_ you're talking about? All I see is simple getter/setter functions there.

Comment: Helpful tip: subtract two values ***after*** they're initialized, not before.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I knew it was something stupid thank you for noticing my ridiculous error.

Comment: No images of text please. They are not useful.

Comment: @usr2564301 The firs commentor requested it. That's the only reason it's up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate profit after the retail price and the wholesale price have been entered. The line

```
p=r-w;
```

causes undefined behavior since neither `r` nor `w` have been assigned a value. Move that line to after the line

```
cin >> w;
```

Here's the udpated function.

```
void setValues(Item& g){
   string n; 
   double r,w,p; 

   cout << "Enter brand name of item: "; 
   cin >> n;
   cout << "Enter retail price: "; 
   cin >> r;
   cout << "Enter wholesale price: "; 
   cin >> w;

   p=r-w;

   g.setName  (n); 
   g.setRprice(r); 
   g.setWprice(w); 
   g.setProfit(p); 
}
```